# How much space does Ubuntu automatically take when installing alongside Windows>

Tags: partitioning, software-installation, windows, disk-usage

If I don't partition my drive before installing and I choose to install alongside Windows 10, how much space will Ubuntu automatically take?

If I do create a partition, how do I also create a swap partition for it?

Will it automatically create a swap partition?

Comment: The way you worded it: the whole disk you pick. But you can't install "alongside windows" when you do not partition before installing. The installer only takes partitions that are available and will delete content on the one you pick. You can delete and create partitions but must have unalllocated space to install in an area that has no older operating system (the installer does not support resizing).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) (the accepted answer) The Ubuntu installer will automatically create a swap partition by default.

Answer (score 1):

During the installation process, you get to decide how big the new partition should be, no automatic formatting is done.

There are no swap partitions any more, in recent releases they have been replace by swap files that grow and shrink in size dynamically.

According to their [System requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements), you will need 5 GB of disk space minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu installer automatically creates a swap partition having size equivalent to your RAM size .
For installation size i think the installer gives an option to choose how much amount of hard disk space you want to allocate to Ubuntu installation . 
Hope it helps you . :)

Comment: We don't use swap partitions anymore. Swap file it nowadays is

Comment: Ohh , Thanks for telling me ! I'm just new to Linux and don't know much about it . Thanks again :)

Answer (score -1):

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10, I did not partition the disk and the installer didn't ask me to. After installation I could see it had created a 35GB partition on my 500GB HDD and installed to that.

Comment: This answers part of the question. Try and add the rest too.

Comment: This is wrong! Ubuntu will find an unallocated space if available and use it. If no unallocated space is available, the Ubuntu installer will display a slider with which the user/installer can allocate the disk space between Windows and Ubuntu partitions.

Comment: @user68186 I think he means that the slider usually rests with 35GB to Ubuntu. It may be true (I have such a memory) but will have to check

Comment: @SasukeUchiha I didn't think of that. It has been a while since I did my dual-boot default installation.

Comment: @user68186 Same here. I also won't be able to test as I don't currently have a VM with windows to do that. Also low on internet